# How to match version number from output

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, grep, regular-expression

With the following `yum info` call we can capture the installed version of `ambari-metrics-monitor`

```
 yum info ambari-metrics-monitor| grep -i version |head -1
 Version     : 2.6.1.0
```

and to verify from output the version is, `2.6.1.0`, I simply do:

```
 yum info ambari-metrics-monitor| grep -i version |head -1 |  grep "2.6.1.0"
```

My feeling is that this way isn't the right way to match the version float number.

So what is the right way to match the version float number from output (according to my example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
package=ambari-metrics-monitor
required_version=2.6.1.0
current_version="$( yum info $package | awk -F: '/Version/ {print $2}' )"

if [[ "$current_version" == "$required_version" ]]; then
    echo "Good to go"
else
    echo "Version mismatch - version $current_version is installed for $package"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

With single **`awk`** command:

```
yum info ambari-metrics-monitor \
| awk -v ver="2.6.1.0" '$1 ~ /[vV]ersion$/ && $3 == ver{ f=1; exit }
                        END{ printf "Version %smatched\n", (f? "" : "not ") }'
```

---

The output will be either `Version matched` or `Version not matched`

Answer (score 1):

If the package is already installed, you can use the `--queryformat` argument of `rpm` to only print the version number, and then use the `-F` and `-x` arguments of `grep` to conveniently do an exact match:

```
rpm -q --queryformat %{VERSION} ambari-metrics-monitor \
| grep -qFx 2.6.10 && echo "version matched"
```

Answer (score 0):

With just `awk` you could do something like:

```
yum info ambari-metrics-monitor \
| awk -F: '/Version/{ if ($2 == " 2.6.1.0") {print "yes"} else exit 1}'
```

Note on my `yum` there is whitespace before the version number so I have had to add it to the check string in order to match.

This will print `yes` (and exit 0) if it matches or exit with 1 if it doesn't